# Integration MSAL plugin (azure ad b2c)/microsoft Oauth for Expo SDK(react native)

Tags: expo, azure-ad-msal

I have been trying to implement Microsft(MSAL) authentication plugin to use in my Expo(React Native) project but I couldn't find resources(MSAL libraries for Expo specific) that would help me with integration. 
Found a question that was asked about that, but didn't see the answer in [Expo Forums](https://forums.expo.io/t/msal-support-azure-ad-b2c/27943). 
I am on windows using Expo. For me it is important to implement MSAL(micrsoft authentication)plugin with Expo(React Native) using windows.
I was wondering if someone is trying to do the same and have an experience?--Thanks in advance.

Comment: curious have you found any info about this?

Comment: I have been unable to do with with out ejecting expo which is a real shame.

Comment: I gave up on this almost 10 months ago and ever since didn't look back. Sorry, I have no answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [react-native-msal](https://github.com/stashenergy/react-native-msal), which supports Expo.

Comment: It doesn't support Expo's managed workflow https://github.com/stashenergy/react-native-msal/issues/51#issuecomment-711173125

Comment: That comment is two years old. The package now supports Expo via a config plugin. https://github.com/stashenergy/react-native-msal#setup

Comment: True. Gotta switch to EAS which is easier than ever.